# Symfony Editing session object

Tags: php, forms, session, post, symfony

Using Symfony 2 I build a page where logged in users could update there details. To do this, in the controller under profileAction I use dotorine to get a user by taking the user id from the session.

```
 $user = $this->getUser();
 $entity = $em->getRepository('GibboCodeKeeperBundle:User')->find($user->getId());
```

I then bind the $entity object a form, however when the form is submitted, everything that has now been updated in the bound $entity object is also changed in the $user object from the session. It also happens visa versa, if I refresh the $user object the $entity also becomes refreshed :S.

I would like to have $entity represent what has come back from inside the form and $user to represent what is currently in the database before attempting to persist, so I can see what the user has updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$entity = $em->getRepository('GibboCodeKeeperBundle:User')->find($user->getId());

$form = $this->createForm($formType, $entity);
$form->bind($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // here is your updated user
    $entity = $form->getData();

    // this will not update uses session
    $em->refresh($user);
}
```

or you can clone entity

```
$oldEntity = clone $entity;
```

Comment: no luck :( both $user and $entity still hold the exact same data :S

Comment: Don't bind the request to the form, thats what actually takes the data from the form and writes it to the entity. you can also get specific data from the form by doing `$form->get('username');`

Comment: clone the entity doesn't work for me, $em->refresh($user) when !$form->isValid() do the trick